# Is there a way to get image names from DSLR to a tethered tablet?

Tags: dslr, file-management, tethering, android, filenames

My implementation would be for high volume photography (sorting/post processing)....

If I can get the image name, as the picture is taken, to be sent to a tethered android tablet, I would be able to sort images almost instantly later in my workflow...

example...
If "Bob" is the subject that I am currently shooting, I could select his name on a companion tablet app (yet to be developed) and then start shooting...every file name would then be placed in the "Bob" folder....then repeat for "jane", etc...

Then, when I get home...dump the data and the pics and I can simply write a bit of code that looks at the data and sorts, tags, adds exif data (whatever i need to do) b/c i would know exactly which files (by name) belong to "bob". "jane"...etc...

Answer (score 1):

I'll make some assumptions that aren't covered in your post.  The images are all stored on the camera while shooting, you are shooting at a fixed location, and you are using a Canon EOS DSLR, like the 70D.  Need more clarification from you.

There are already apps out there that allow you to connect your Android to your camera, so it can definitely be done.  [DSLR Controller (BETA)](http://dslrcontroller.com/) is one example.  You could write your app to allow you to create a profile for your subject, take all the photos with you camera while the app monitors file names, then download the pictures later and post process them as necessary.

Another option may be to setup a connection with your camera and a laptop.  Connect with the EOS utility and save all the shot pictures to a folder on the laptop as you shoot them.  You can create a folder for each subject and name it appropriately.  When you change subjects, simply create a new folder, change the utility preferences and start shooting.  This seems like it could be a lot simpler than your previous method.

Although, it is all based on the assumptions.

P.S.: If you want more details on the EOS Utility, you can read about it [HERE](http://kbsupport.cusa.canon.com/system/selfservice.controller?CONFIGURATION=1011&PARTITION_ID=1&secureFlag=false&TIMEZONE_OFFSET&CMD=VIEW_ARTICLE&ARTICLE_ID=61654)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Point(s) of clarification...
Canon 5DmrkII, not necessarily a fixed location....for example, I might be doing Team/Individual photos for youth sports on a football field. Images stored on camera card while shooting.

I've considered laptop tethering, using light-room, Canon EOS etc but I'd really like to keep it super "lightweight" on location...

I did come across DLSR Controller, but didn't see anything about sending the filename TO the tablet...just not really sure where to start w/ that....

Answer (score 0):

You might want to explore ShutterSnitch with an EyeFi wireless SD card as ShutterSnitch has  support for collections. 
While this doesn't address your need to name the files in sequence as far as I know (I admittedly haven't used it in a while), it does present a method which would allow virtual folders (collections) for easy sorting of clients.

For the record, I had a similar problem as what you've explained, but in the studio. I  ended up using CaptureOne, a laptop, a TV and an iPad to solve a different problem that allowed me to:

- Tether to a large screen for stylists/agents/parents
- Broadcast the shoot to an iPad that the subject could look at
- Allow me to create sessions that still allowed review on the iPad

This doesn't address being on the playing field, but is a great workflow for studio work.

Two answers for one here, and both cost money, but might be able to sort out the problem.

Comment: thanks for the input and ideas Ryan!  I'll have to take a closer look at these....yeah, if i was trying to solve this in a studio setting, seems like it would be a lot "easier" (relatively speaking)  :)  The other approach I was exploring was adding to the meta data/EXIF data, in camera, as its being shot...using some tethered app.

So, instead of GETTING the image name, I would select "BOB" from the app and "BOB" would have a unique ID (say 12345) associated w/ him...then I would add that ID to the EXIF data (comment field perhaps) of every picture I took...but that seems a lot harder. :(